# Silent notifications on Android

Tags: android, notifications

Hello fellow programmers. 
I have a problem and would appreciate any insights.
An app that I'm developing should receive notifications - silent and regular.
When the app is open or in background everything is good, I receive every notification in a "silent" way and if logic requires it I pop a local notification.
The problem is when app is closed (cleared from background),  I need to get a silent notification but every notification is handled by the operating system and pops it for the user to see.
What should I do to handle the app closed case?
Thanks.

Comment: Use a Service? Use GCM?

Comment: Do you have a tutorial for such a service?

Comment: I think there's no magic or exact tutorial for what you want to achieve. You should start learning about them and then you'll realize that though them there are many ways to get what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not default behavior but you could achieve this by using a dirty logic. In your receiver/service class [who generates notification], just check any activity of your required application is active or not. If your application is not in active state than don't generate the notification.